# Dynamically add around_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on adding some methods to a controller dynamically.

```
def self.add_command(method)
  define_method(method) do
    # Do something
  end
end

add_command :method_name
```

I would like to add an around filter for these methods and only these, but do it dynamically. When I simply try to add an `around_filter` call in the `add_command` method it doesn't get triggered.

How is it possible to dynamically add an around filter?

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.add_command(method)
  define_method(method) do
    # Do something
  end
  class_eval do
    around_filter method.to_sym
  end
end
```